# JavaBean as Datasource in iReport: "NoClassDefFoundError" (jar is in the classpath!)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans, ireport

I am using *JasperReports 5.6* via API.

I am building a report using *iReport*. The problem is that I've already set a jar with bean factory in the classpath of *iReport* as

```
com.myname.beanproject.beanpackage.BeanFactoryClass
```

Also I set up static method to call a list of beans:

```
getEntries
```

but still getting a error while testing a connection.
What am I doing wrong?

Error is

```
NoClassDefFoundError!
Check your classpath!
Could not initialize class com.myname.beanproject.beanpackage.BeanFactoryClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I added org.slf4j.loggerfactory to the classpath, and error changed. Now it's just "General problem" without any explanation.